# How to make a bus destination blind on roblox?

Tags: roblox

I'm a bus developer on the site roblox and I'm trying to work out how to make destination blinds such as the image attached. I've been using other developers destination blinds from Free Models but thought it would be a good Idea to create my own. If anyone could help me that would be great.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Unfortunately, there is no image attached, and your question is pretty broad! See [ask] and share a [mcve] if your problem is indeed related to coding...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to display custom text on a surface of a part.
In that case, you should use a SurfaceGui combined with a TextLabel.

The wiki page "Beginner's GUI Tutorial" might be helpful:
http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Beginner%27s_GUI_Tutorial#GUI_Types